# n-tier architecture solution. How better?

Tags: architecture, n-tier-architecture

I need to create n-tier application with the following parts:

1. Data server
2. Business logic server
3. Lightweight client with custom features for each customer

Data server(1) and l/w client(3) will be placed on customer server.
Application will be as service and all business logic(2) will work on my servers.
That is simple, yes. **But!** Data server owned by customer and data is secret for each customer. I can't hold data on my servers, but i want to publish lightweight clients on customer's side. All clients from all customers will use the same business logic from my server.

Question is:

**How can i connect clients(3) with business logic(2) and protect the data to be transferred from customers?**

My first solution is VPN or SSH tunnel, but may be there is another way?
Or may be another approach.

Also data transfer between data server and business logic server may be so slow, that because i'm trying to find another approach for this architecture.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it necessary to put the middle tier (business logic) on your server? Can you simply put it on the client server?

Comment: Necessary, because it must be SaaS and if i have new features in business logic, i dont want to update application for each customer, just update on my server and each customer has latest version.

Comment: this is not the idea of ​​SaaS, i dont want to install business logic application on customer's computers

Comment: Then you can re-consider SaaS in this case :) Clearly SaaS is simpler when the customer data is stored in the cloud as well. Anyway, @Hadi's answer below holds the key to your problem - read up on multi-tenancy.

Comment: :) SaaS does not make to store data in cloud, idea is one instance of application for all clients and centralized application logic as i mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing two things here:

-The architecture: I think you'd better google "Multi-Tenant application" designs as this matches the description of your system.

-Security concerns: If this is a web application (which I think it is as you mentioned lightweight) you're better off with a SSL certificate which encrypts all traffic to/from your server by using HTTPS. If that is not applicable, you can chose SSH or VPN as they have almost the same requirements and affect the application the same.

Comment: You should take a look at salesforce.com as one of the largest examples of a multi-tenant SaaS